# Determinar cuando se cierre un proceso windows

Tags: vb.net, windows, windows-forms

Quiero determinar en código vb cuando se cierra un proceso de windows (que previamente he abierto). Pero me sale un error cuando quiere ejecutar:

```
Call GetExitCodeProcess(handle_Process, lp_ExitCode)
```

Y el mensaje de error es: **"Intento de leer o escribir en la memoria protegida. A menudo, esto indica que hay otra memoria dañada."**

Me estoy basando en el código de la siguiente pagina: 
[Abrir proceso y esperar a que finalice](http://www.recursosvisualbasic.com.ar/htm/listado-api/205-abrir-programa-esperar-a-que-termine.htm)

Comment: Por favor, incluye en tu pregunta [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). También, revisa las etiquetas. No es posible que estés usando vb.net, vba y vbscript a la vez.

Comment: @Pedro: Hubiera sido mejor dejar que OP aclare las etiquetas para evitar un error de interpretación. No es enteramente claro que la pregunta tenga que ver con vb.net. Y puede que la etiqueta windows-forms haya sido un error como las demás etiquetas.

Comment: @sstan tendré mas cuidado para la proxima vez, zorry

Comment: Perdón, lo tendré en cuenta lo de las etiquetas.

Answer (score 1):

```
' En esta parte obtiene los permisos del proceso para
' modificarlo (por decirlo de algun manera)
' Sin esto el programa no funciona, Asegurate de tener esta parte en tu codigo
handle_Process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, id_process)  


//Mientras lp_ExitCode = STATUS_PENDING, se ejecuta el do  
Do  

    Call GetExitCodeProcess(handle_Process, lp_ExitCode)
```

Comment: Hola Hector, te comento que si tiene esa parte. Me estoy basando en el codigo que esta en la pagina: http://www.recursosvisualbasic.com.ar/htm/listado-api/205-abrir-programa-esperar-a-que-termine.htm

Answer (score 1):

Esto puede ocurrir si estas usando el debugger (codigo administrado) y ademas utilizas librerias nativas.

Algunas soluciones pueden ser:

- Usar debuggers sin código administrado,
- evitar la operacion de turno en debug y luego probar en release, o
- desactivar la excepción en tiempo de ejecución que te este saltando, si esta disponible, en Depurar->Ventanas->Configuración de excepciones.